# Как получить корректный auth ключ для post запроса

Tags: python, requests, веб-скрейпинг

Пытаюсь спарсить товары по скидке с магазина "Перекрёсток" https://www.perekrestok.ru/. Если перейти в  раздел **скидки** и  обновить страницу, то можно найти XHR файл с названием **feed**. Он содержит все нужные мне данные, но для post запроса по ссылке https://www.perekrestok.ru/api/customer/1.4.1.0/catalog/product/feed к нему необходим заголовок
**Auth**. Проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю, где найти корректный auth ключ. Я попытался достать его из заголовков запроса, содержащего HTML-код страницы, но эти данные отличаются:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Слева** auth ключ, который я получаю. А **справа** нужный ключ.

В итоге при моем значении ключа я вроде получаю данные, но в них отсутсвуют некоторые товары и есть неправильные цены. Предполагаю, что это из-за неправильного ключа, ведь **в postman при правильно ключе выдает корректные данные.**

***Вопрос: Как получить кооректный ключ?***

Сам python код:

```
import requests
import json

# получение Auth ключа
cookieurl = "https://www.perekrestok.ru/cat/d"
r = requests.get(cookieurl)
s = r.headers["Set-Cookie"].replace("%7B", "{").replace("%22", '"').replace("%3A", ":").replace("%2C", ",").replace("%7D", "}")
s1 = s[8:s.find(";")]
auth = json.loads(s1)["accessToken"]
print(auth)


# Начальные данные
page = 1
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Auth': 'Bearer ' + auth
           }
url = "https://www.perekrestok.ru/api/customer/1.4.1.0/catalog/product/feed"
sales = []


# Парсинг
while True:
    payload = json.dumps({
        "page": page,
        "perPage": 48,
        "filter": {
            "promoListing": 1
        },
        "withBestProductReviews": False
    })
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    content = response.json()
    if len(content["content"]["items"]) == 0:
        break
    for product in content["content"]["items"]:
        name = product["title"]
        old_price = str(product["priceTag"]["grossPrice"])
        old_price = old_price[:-2] + "." + old_price[-2:]
        new_price = str(product["priceTag"]["price"])
        new_price = new_price[:-2] + "." + new_price[-2:]
        s = f'Старая цена - {old_price} рублей, Новая цена - {new_price} рублей'
        sales.append([name, s])
    print(page)
    page += 1
```